# GraphRequest﹕ Warning: Request without access token missing application ID or client token

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Im using latest Facebook SDK(v4.2.0) for android.

When I tried to post open graph story, logcat says: **GraphRequest﹕ Warning: Request without access token missing application ID or client token** and story is not being post.

My onCreate method code is:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {//@Overridden method});
}
```

And Later I called following code from button's onClickListener

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("publish_action"));
```

I have also handled callback as:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

}

The code I used for open graph post is:

```
 Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("match", "http://samples.ogp.me/413385652011237");

    GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "me/tigertraptest:complete",
            params,
            HttpMethod.POST
    );
    GraphResponse response = request.executeAndWait();
```

Also I have tried all solution suggested in this link: [failed solution](http://code2care.org/2015/facebook-warning:-request-without-access-token-missing-application-id-or-client-token/).

I'm new to Facebook Integration. Please help.

**Edit I have posted all codes that I used in my activity to enable Facebook open graph post.**

Comment: ShareDialog does not require an access token. Are you sure your failure here isn't just that you don't have a valid access token?

Comment: @MingLi I am saying I used shareDialog before using open graph to post. Its just for your information I wanted to make clear that I have successfully configured by Facebook SDK and added my development hash key. Do you have any suggestion why this error is showing?

Comment: This error is showing because you don't have an access token. You need to implement Facebook Login, and also ask for the publish_actions permission before you can share using the Graph API. Alternatively, you can construct the open graph action, and use shareDialog to share (instead of GraphRequest). Using share dialog does not require any special permissions or an access token.

Comment: @MingLi I have already done that using shareDialog but I want to use Graph Api as it looks more standard. I've also used LoginManager with write permission and publish action, but error remain same. Would you please clearify how to use this graph API?

Comment: All I can say at this point is to put a breakpoint just before you create the GraphRequest, and check that you have a valid access token. You can also look at the HelloFacebook sample that ships with the SDK.

Comment: you missed to override onActivityResult

Answer (score 0):

You have to use accesstokentracker  to track your accesstoken since it changes after some time. You also have to add the method  onCurrentAccessTokenChanged. You can refer to 
[Getting null response in android fb graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907807/getting-null-response-in-android-fb-graph-api)
for the code. Although  in that code, group feeds are being fetched but you cam see the part related to access token.

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass access token also.

```
params.putString("access_token", "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN");
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Passing in AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() to the GraphRequest will allow it to auto add the access_token parameter.